# Display an image in html file in iphone

Tags: html, objective-c, ios4

Hi All
I want to load an image from HTMl file in IPHone
but i m unable to do that
plz edit my code for this-

```
UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 650, 768)];
NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Rough" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *fileContents=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

[webView loadHTMLString:fileContents baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

&.html is-

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<img src=”HomePage.png”>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

how i can show this image in WebView.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're setting baseURL to nil.  If you want the image to load, surely you have to specify it, or how else does it know where "HomePage.png" is?

Where is HomePage.png stored?  On the internet, or in the app bundle?  Use a `file://` URL if it's stored in the app bundle, specify the proper URL if it's stored online.

UPDATE: Based on your comment, it looks like you're setting the base URL as the top level of the .app bundle.

Complete code as requested.

I'm assuming you have this directory layout:

```
YourApp.app/
  Contents/
    Resources/
      Rough.html
      Images/
        HomePage.png
      ...
```

Therefore both your baseURL needs to be set to the Resources URL, and the `<img>` tag in the HTML needs to have `Images/` in the `src` attribute.

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *resourcesURL = [[mainBundle bundleURL]
                              stringByAppendingString:@"Contents/Resources"];
NSString *htmlURL = [resourcesURL stringByAppendingString:@"/Rough.html"];

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:htmlURL
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error:NULL];

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 650, 768)];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:resourcesURL];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

And the HTML should be:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="Images/HomePage.png" alt="Your placeholder text" />
  </body>
</html>
```

(Untested)

PS: Curly quotes “ and “ are NOT the same as ASCII double quotes " and " in almost all programming languages.  Be careful about using them.

Comment: image in Resource in appBundel.

Comment: i m doing this-NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath];
  NSURL *bundleBaseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];
  
  NSString *_path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Rough" ofType:@"html"]; 
  NSString *fileContents=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:_path];
  [webView loadHTMLString:fileContents baseURL:bundleBaseURL];
But it is still not showing the image.

Comment: You should update the question to indicate this.  Have you confirmed that the image exists?  Something like `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"HomePage.png"]];`.  Also, this code is assuming the image is stored in the top level of your .app bundle.  That's probably wrong, and if not, you should consider moving it somewhere else (Resources?).

Comment: I have HomePage.png in my Resources/Images directory. you plz plz give me the complete code for displaying an image from html file.i m trying it from last 4 hours.

Comment: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"HomePage.png"]]; returning true means image is existing.

Comment: HI Thanks again..as you have untested it...so plz test it bcoz it is not working properly....but thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you put anything else in the HTML?  Like some text, just to see that it's actually even rendering your HTML?

Comment: yeh..text is rendering my friend.